# RestTemplate unable to populate object

Tags: java, spring, rest, jaxb, spring-web

I have following code to send request and receive a response, it seems like everything is configured but the code is returning `NullPointerException`.

I am not sure whats missing. I printed out readyURL variable which has the correct URL address. The stackTrace does not offer much.

**Code**

```
try {
    final String APIKEY = "MYAPI";
    final String URL = "http://api-sandbox.seatwave.com/v2/discovery/events?apikey="
            + APIKEY;
    String readyUrl = URL + "&what=" + name;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    EventsResponse eventResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(readyUrl,
            EventsResponse.class);

    System.err.println("seatwave>>>"
            + eventResponse.getEvents().getEvent().size()); //line 245
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventsResponse {
    @XmlElement
    private Status status;
    @XmlElement(name = "Paging")
    private Page page;
    @XmlElement
    private Events events;

    public Status getStatus() {
      return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
      this.status = status;
    }

    public Page getPage() {
      return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Page page) {
      this.page = page;
    }

    public Events getEvents() {
      return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(Events events) {
      this.events = events;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Status {
    @XmlElement(name = "Version")
    private double version;
    @XmlElement(name = "TimeStampUtc")
    private Date timeStampUtc;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private int code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "Details")
    private String details;

   public double getVersion() {
      return version;
   }

    public void setVersion(double version) {
      this.version = version;
    }

    public Date getTimeStampUtc() {
      return timeStampUtc;
    }

    public void setTimeStampUtc(Date timeStampUtc) {
      this.timeStampUtc = timeStampUtc;
    }

    public int getCode() {
     return code;
    }

  public void setCode(int code) {
     this.code = code;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
     return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
     this.message = message;
  }

  public String getDetails() {
     return details;
  }

  public void setDetails(String details) {
     this.details = details;
  }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Page")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Page {
    @XmlElement(name="PageNumber")
    private int pageNumber;
    @XmlElement(name="PageSize")
    private int pageSize;
    @XmlElement(name="PageResultCount")
    private int pageResultCount;
    @XmlElement(name="TotalResultCount")
    private int totalResultCount;
    @XmlElement(name="TotalPageCount")
    private int totalPageCount;

    public int getPageNumber() {
      return pageNumber;
    }

    public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
       this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
      return pageSize;
   }

   public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
      this.pageSize = pageSize;
   }

   public int getPageResultCount() {
      return pageResultCount;
   }

   public void setPageResultCount(int pageResultCount) {
      this.pageResultCount = pageResultCount;
   }

   public int getTotalResultCount() {
      return totalResultCount;
   }

   public void setTotalResultCount(int totalResultCount) {
      this.totalResultCount = totalResultCount;
   }

   public int getTotalPageCount() {
      return totalPageCount;
   }

   public void setTotalPageCount(int totalPageCount) {
     this.totalPageCount = totalPageCount;
   }

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Events {
    @XmlElement
    private List<Event> event;

    public List<Event> getEvent() {
      return event;
    }  

    public void setEvent(List<Event> event) {
      this.event = event;
    }
 }

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event {
    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Date")
    private Date date;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupName")
    private String eventGroupName;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueName")
    private String venueName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Town")
    private String town;
    @XmlElement(name = "Country")
    private String country;
    @XmlElement(name = "TicketCount")
    private int ticketCount;
    @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
    private String currency;
    @XmlElement(name = "MinPrice")
    private double minPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwURL")
    private String swUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupImageURL")
    private String eventGroupImageUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "LayoutId")
    private int layoutId;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupId")
    private int eventGroupId;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueId")
    private int venueId;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwSellURL")
    private String swSellUrl;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
      return date;
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
      this.date = date;
  }

  public String getEventGroupName() {
     return eventGroupName;
  }

  public void setEventGroupName(String eventGroupName) {
        this.eventGroupName = eventGroupName;
  }

  public String getVenueName() {
      return venueName;
  }

  public void setVenueName(String venueName) {
      this.venueName = venueName;
  }

  public String getTown() {
     return town;
  }

  public void setTown(String town) {
     this.town = town;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
     return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
  }

  public int getTicketCount() {
        return ticketCount;
  }

  public void setTicketCount(int ticketCount) {
        this.ticketCount = ticketCount;
  }

  public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
  }

  public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
  }

  public double getMinPrice() {
        return minPrice;
  }

  public void setMinPrice(double minPrice) {
        this.minPrice = minPrice;
  }

  public String getSwUrl() {
        return swUrl;
  }

  public void setSwUrl(String swUrl) {
        this.swUrl = swUrl;
  }

  public String getEventGroupImageUrl() {
        return eventGroupImageUrl;
  }

  public void setEventGroupImageUrl(String eventGroupImageUrl) {
        this.eventGroupImageUrl = eventGroupImageUrl;
  }

  public int getLayoutId() {
        return layoutId;
  }

  public void setLayoutId(int layoutId) {
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
  }

  public int getEventGroupId() {
        return eventGroupId;
  }

  public void setEventGroupId(int eventGroupId) {
        this.eventGroupId = eventGroupId;
  }

  public int getVenueId() {
        return venueId;
  }

  public void setVenueId(int venueId) {
        this.venueId = venueId;
  }

  public String getSwSellUrl() {
        return swSellUrl;
  }

  public void setSwSellUrl(String swSellUrl) {
        this.swSellUrl = swSellUrl;
  }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myproject.tickets.service.TicketSeviceImpl.seatWave(TicketSeviceImpl.java:245)
    at com.myproject.tickets.service.TicketSeviceImpl.findTicket(TicketSeviceImpl.java:45)
    at com.myproject.web.TicketController.findTicket(TicketController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Sample result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventsResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Status>
      <Version>2.0</Version>
      <TimeStampUtc>2015-09-27T08:44:24</TimeStampUtc>
      <Code>0</Code>
      <Message>Success</Message>
      <Details />
   </Status>
   <Paging>
      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
      <PageSize>50</PageSize>
      <PageResultCount>50</PageResultCount>
      <TotalResultCount>7889</TotalResultCount>
      <TotalPageCount>158</TotalPageCount>
   </Paging>
   <Events>
      <Event>
         <Id>948040</Id>
         <Date>2015-09-27T14:30:00</Date>
         <EventGroupName>The Lion King - London</EventGroupName>
         <VenueName>Lyceum Theatre London</VenueName>
         <Town>London</Town>
         <Country>UK</Country>
         <TicketCount>183</TicketCount>
         <Currency>GBP</Currency>
         <MinPrice>29.75</MinPrice>
         <SwURL>http://www.seatwave.com/the-lion-king-london-tickets/lyceum-theatre--tickets/27-september-2015/perf/948040?affid=&amp;appid=203710</SwURL>
         <EventGroupImageURL>http://z.stwv.im/filestore/season/image/the-lion-king_000277_1_mainpicture.jpg</EventGroupImageURL>
         <LayoutId>232</LayoutId>
         <EventGroupId>277</EventGroupId>
         <VenueId>232</VenueId>
         <SwSellURL>http://www.seatwave.com/sellticketdetails?performanceId=948040&amp;affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwSellURL>
      </Event>
      <Event>
         <Id>987509</Id>
         <Date>2015-09-27T15:00:00</Date>
         <EventGroupName>American Idiot</EventGroupName>
         <VenueName>Arts Theatre London</VenueName>
         <Town>London</Town>
         <Country>UK</Country>
         <TicketCount>28</TicketCount>
         <Currency>GBP</Currency>
         <MinPrice>35.7</MinPrice>
         <SwURL>http://www.seatwave.com/american-idiot-tickets/arts-theatre-tickets/27-september-2015/perf/987509?affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwURL>
         <EventGroupImageURL>http://z.stwv.im/filestore/season/image/americanidiot_32152_1_1_20111209091615.jpg</EventGroupImageURL>
         <LayoutId>4576</LayoutId>
         <EventGroupId>32152</EventGroupId>
         <VenueId>4207</VenueId>
         <SwSellURL>http://www.seatwave.com/sellticketdetails?performanceId=987509&amp;affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwSellURL>
      </Event>
      <Event>
         <Id>948273</Id>
         <Date>2015-09-27T15:00:00</Date>
         <EventGroupName>Matilda The Musical</EventGroupName>
         <VenueName>Cambridge Theatre</VenueName>
```

**Update**

I added this code right after restTemplate.getForObject line but nothing will be shown on console.

```
if(eventResponse == null)
            {
                System.err.println("it is null");
            }else{

            System.err.println("message:>>"+eventResponse.getStatus().getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Where is your stack trace? Have you tried debugging your code? Do you see any output in response?

Comment: @SMA stack trace is included. I am still working on it. I checked the generated URL thats correct and returns correct results.

Comment: which line is `t com.myproject.tickets.service.TicketSeviceImpl.seatWave(TicketSeviceImpl.java:245)` referring to?

Comment: @SMA I just mentioned that in question. Thats where it need to show the size of returned events.

Comment: Why do people click on close before telling the reason? You guys should tell me your reason so I try to avoid what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So, `eventResponse.getEvents().getEvent().size()` throws a NPE. That means that eventResponse is null, or eventResponse.getEvents() is null, or eventResponse.getEvents().getEvent() is null. Use your debugger to find out.

Comment: @JBNizet I doubt the correctness of JAXB related classes. Whats the best way to debug it? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: my guess would be that the problem is the deserialization of the xml. do you do anything fancy in your getter/setters that might cause troubles?

Comment: @Dirk no I just generated them with Eclipse.

Comment: calling readyURL in the browser gives you the correct data?

Comment: @Dirk yet it does, thats why I doubt the correctness of deserialisation.

Comment: is eventResponse null?

Comment: @Dirk I just included all setters and getters, yes it seems like thats null

Comment: @RC question is about JAXB and RestTemplate, totally diffrent.

Comment: Try using `@XmlElement private List<Event> events;` in your `EventsReponse`

Comment: @RC. still the same issue

Comment: Your XML element mapping names doesn't match the case in the actual XML. `eventsResponse` instead of `EventsResponse`. Make the appropriate changes, eg. `@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsResponse")`

Answer (score 1):

I made your code working by some mapping changes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsResponse") // added (name = "EventsResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "Status")
    private Status status;
    @XmlElement(name = "Paging")
    private Page page;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Events") // added
    @XmlElement(name = "Event") // added (name = "Event")
    private List<Event> events;

    // getters, setter
}

@XmlRootElement // removed name =
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Page {
    @XmlElement(name = "PageNumber")
    private int pageNumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "PageSize")
    private int pageSize;
    @XmlElement(name = "PageResultCount")
    private int pageResultCount;
    @XmlElement(name = "TotalResultCount")
    private int totalResultCount;
    @XmlElement(name = "TotalPageCount")
    private int totalPageCount;

    // getters, setter
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Status {
    @XmlElement(name = "Version")
    private double version;
    @XmlElement(name = "TimeStampUtc")
    private Date timeStampUtc;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private int code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "Details")
    private String details;

    // getters, setter
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event {
    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Date")
    private Date date;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupName")
    private String eventGroupName;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueName")
    private String venueName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Town")
    private String town;
    @XmlElement(name = "Country")
    private String country;
    @XmlElement(name = "TicketCount")
    private int ticketCount;
    @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
    private String currency;
    @XmlElement(name = "MinPrice")
    private double minPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwURL")
    private String swUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupImageURL")
    private String eventGroupImageUrl;
    @XmlElement(name = "LayoutId")
    private int layoutId;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupId")
    private int eventGroupId;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueId")
    private int venueId;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwSellURL")
    private String swSellUrl;

    // getters, setter
}
```

then I did test it using [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/):

```
package so32806530;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

public class App {

    private static final String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<EventsResponse xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +
            "   <Status>\n" +
            "      <Version>2.0</Version>\n" +
            "      <TimeStampUtc>2015-09-27T08:44:24</TimeStampUtc>\n" +
            "      <Code>0</Code>\n" +
            "      <Message>Success</Message>\n" +
            "      <Details />\n" +
            "   </Status>\n" +
            "   <Paging>\n" +
            "      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>\n" +
            "      <PageSize>50</PageSize>\n" +
            "      <PageResultCount>50</PageResultCount>\n" +
            "      <TotalResultCount>7889</TotalResultCount>\n" +
            "      <TotalPageCount>158</TotalPageCount>\n" +
            "   </Paging>\n" +
            "   <Events>\n" +
            "      <Event>\n" +
            "         <Id>948040</Id>\n" +
            "         <Date>2015-09-27T14:30:00</Date>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupName>The Lion King - London</EventGroupName>\n" +
            "         <VenueName>Lyceum Theatre London</VenueName>\n" +
            "         <Town>London</Town>\n" +
            "         <Country>UK</Country>\n" +
            "         <TicketCount>183</TicketCount>\n" +
            "         <Currency>GBP</Currency>\n" +
            "         <MinPrice>29.75</MinPrice>\n" +
            "         <SwURL>http://www.seatwave.com/the-lion-king-london-tickets/lyceum-theatre--tickets/27-september-2015/perf/948040?affid=&amp;appid=203710</SwURL>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupImageURL>http://z.stwv.im/filestore/season/image/the-lion-king_000277_1_mainpicture.jpg</EventGroupImageURL>\n" +
            "         <LayoutId>232</LayoutId>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupId>277</EventGroupId>\n" +
            "         <VenueId>232</VenueId>\n" +
            "         <SwSellURL>http://www.seatwave.com/sellticketdetails?performanceId=948040&amp;affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwSellURL>\n" +
            "      </Event>\n" +
            "      <Event>\n" +
            "         <Id>987509</Id>\n" +
            "         <Date>2015-09-27T15:00:00</Date>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupName>American Idiot</EventGroupName>\n" +
            "         <VenueName>Arts Theatre London</VenueName>\n" +
            "         <Town>London</Town>\n" +
            "         <Country>UK</Country>\n" +
            "         <TicketCount>28</TicketCount>\n" +
            "         <Currency>GBP</Currency>\n" +
            "         <MinPrice>35.7</MinPrice>\n" +
            "         <SwURL>http://www.seatwave.com/american-idiot-tickets/arts-theatre-tickets/27-september-2015/perf/987509?affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwURL>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupImageURL>http://z.stwv.im/filestore/season/image/americanidiot_32152_1_1_20111209091615.jpg</EventGroupImageURL>\n" +
            "         <LayoutId>4576</LayoutId>\n" +
            "         <EventGroupId>32152</EventGroupId>\n" +
            "         <VenueId>4207</VenueId>\n" +
            "         <SwSellURL>http://www.seatwave.com/sellticketdetails?performanceId=987509&amp;affid=&amp;appid=2037810</SwSellURL>\n" +
            "      </Event>\n" +
            "   </Events>\n" +
            "</EventsResponse>";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // ---------- starts fake API server -----
        final WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().port(8089));
        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlMatching("/v2/discovery/events.*")).willReturn(aResponse().withHeader("Content-type", "application/xml").withStatus(200).withBody(XML)));
        wireMockServer.start();
        // ---------------------------------------

        try {
            final String name = "foo";
            final String APIKEY = "MYAPI";
            final String URL = "http://localhost:8089/v2/discovery/events?apikey=" + APIKEY;
            final String readyUrl = URL + "&what=" + name;
            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            final EventsResponse eventResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(readyUrl, EventsResponse.class);

            System.err.println("seatwave>>>" + eventResponse.getEvents().size());

            for (final Event event : eventResponse.getEvents()) {
                System.out.println("EventID: " + event.getId());
            }
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // ---------- stops fake API server ------    
        wireMockServer.stop();
        // ---------------------------------------
    }
}
```

Output:

```
seatwave>>>2
EventID: 948040
EventID: 987509
```

Some reading about JAXB and collections: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html (NB: not my blog)

---

Versions used:

- spring-web: 4.0.5.RELEASE
- jaxb-api: 2.2.1
- wiremock: 1.57

Comment: I tried that but stilll has same issue will try wiremock.

Comment: I did add some comment (added / removed), I also completed your truncated xml (the posted one is invalid). This works so if you don't get it to work with your server, you should get some exception from `restTemplate`

Comment: Do you know of any alternative to WireMock?

Comment: Alternative to do what, I don't have access to your API server so I did mock it, you have to use the real thing (url `http://api-sandbox.seatwave.com/v2/discovery/events...`).

Comment: I mean any other library similar to wiremock to mock?

Comment: I don't know, why do you need that?

Comment: I tried your code, thats weird it does not work for me. Do you mind I give you the complete response and you test it in your code.

Comment: I did upload a small project [here](https://github.com/Regisc/so32806530), you can hack it the way you want (response is in `src/main/resources/response.xml`).

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works but the response that I receive from server does not work. I think the reason is the response starts with '<EventsResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' not header of xml.

Comment: @DanielNewtown That's not the problem, I got another sample response from the seatwave (with the XML start you mentioned) and RC's code still works.

Comment: @DanielNewtown Post the XML response you get, stack traces, etc. Can't help you with no details.

Answer (score 1):

### I was able to get Spring's RestTemplate to work with [SeatWave's API](http://developer.seatwave.com/API/)

Here is a working example on github:https://github.com/cosbor11/seatwave-spring-client-example

### Here are the Steps:

1. Enter the following GET url into a browser:

   http://api-sandbox.seatwave.com/v2/discovery/events?apikey=4739E4694D0E482A92C9D0B478D83934&what=music
2. View the source and copy paste the xml into a [xsd generator](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx).
3. Generate the xsd with `Russian Doll Style` selected.
4. Paste the generated content into a new file located some where like here: `${home}/Desktop/schema.xsd`.
5. Remove the first line if it looks like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`
6. Create a **binding.xml** file, that looks like this:

   ```
   <jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
       <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
   </jaxb:bindings>
   ```
7. Create a src file: `mkdir src`.
8. Generate the Java Jaxb classes into that folder using XJC like this:

   `xjc -b ~/Desktop/binding.xml -d src -p com.yourcompany ~/Desktop/schema.xsd`
9. Make sure you copy the generated classes and package structure into your build path.
10. Also, in you build path, create a class with a `main` method that uses your RestTemplate:

    ```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {

            String name = "music";
            final String APIKEY = "4739E4694D0E482A92C9D0B478D83934"; //http://api-sandbox.seatwave.com/v2/discovery/events?apikey=4739E4694D0E482A92C9D0B478D83934&what=music
            final String URL = "http://api-sandbox.seatwave.com/v2/discovery/events?apikey=" + APIKEY;
            String readyUrl = URL + "&what=" + name;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            EventsResponse eventResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(readyUrl, EventsResponse.class);

            System.err.println("seatwave>>>" + eventResponse.getEvents().getEvent().size());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ```
11. Compile that class and run the `main` method. In this example you should get 50 records as the size. Notice that even if you change the `name` variable to something that returns an empty set, there will not be a `NullPointerExeption`.

### Here is what the generated JAXB classes look like:

**EventResponse.java:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "status",
    "paging",
    "events"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsResponse")
public class EventsResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Status", required = true)
    protected Status status;
    @XmlElement(name = "Paging", required = true)
    protected Paging paging;
    @XmlElement(name = "Events", required = true)
    protected Events events;

    //getters & setters
```

**Events.java:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "event"
})
public class Events {

    @XmlElement(name = "Event", required = true)
    protected List<Event> event;

    public List<Event> getEvent() {
        if (event == null) {
            event = new ArrayList<Event>();
        }
        return this.event;
    }

}
```

**Event.java:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "date",
    "eventGroupName",
    "venueName",
    "town",
    "country",
    "ticketCount",
    "currency",
    "minPrice",
    "swURL",
    "eventGroupImageURL",
    "layoutId",
    "eventGroupId",
    "venueId",
    "swSellURL"
})
public class Event {

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    protected int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Date", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupName", required = true)
    protected String eventGroupName;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueName", required = true)
    protected String venueName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Town", required = true)
    protected String town;
    @XmlElement(name = "Country", required = true)
    protected String country;
    @XmlElement(name = "TicketCount")
    protected int ticketCount;
    @XmlElement(name = "Currency", required = true)
    protected String currency;
    @XmlElement(name = "MinPrice", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal minPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwURL", required = true)
    protected String swURL;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupImageURL", required = true)
    protected String eventGroupImageURL;
    @XmlElement(name = "LayoutId")
    protected int layoutId;
    @XmlElement(name = "EventGroupId")
    protected int eventGroupId;
    @XmlElement(name = "VenueId")
    protected int venueId;
    @XmlElement(name = "SwSellURL", required = true)
    protected String swSellURL;

    //getter & setters
```

> **Notes:**
>
> - If you are using maven, there are some nifty tools to generate the jaxb classes into your `generated-sources` folder automatically. I recommend [cxf-xjc-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html).
> - Notice that `Events#getEvent()` method returns a new List if the event property is null.
> - The binding.xml file is handy for customizing the way your jaxb is generated, if you play around with it I bet you can figure out how to get the API classes to be interacted with in a more intuitive way. For example in you main class you could get the size by calling `eventResponse.getEvents().size()` instead of `eventResponse.getEvents().getEvent().size()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventsResponse {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="event")
    private List<Event> events;

}
```

and the Events class can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I did that still the same issue.

Comment: I even changed the annotation to these two but still the same exception is thrown  @XmlElement(name="Events") and @XmlElement(name="Event")